# Reactstrap: Flicker noted on carousel implementation

Tags: reactjs, carousel, bootstrap-4, flicker, reactstrap

- components: Carousel
- reactstrap version 5.0.0-alpha.3
- react version #16
- bootstrap version #4.0.0.beta2

Hi,

I've implemented reactstrap (which is a great tool!) in my app. I've added a carousel at the top of my home page. It cycles 4 images with captions. I'm using the latest react. I've noted a flicker on my page when using the carousel. It happens every now and again and the viewable page seems to flicker/flash once for a less than a second and then everything back to normal. The flicker/flash seems to show the contents of the page below the carousel but its really hard to tell.

I've tried everything I can think of to correct that. I've even use will-change: transform css property to prepare the browser for performance. Nothing has worked.

I wonder if its an issue with react v16 or if theres an issue with using the alpha version of reactstrap. That said I can't seem to correct the issue.

Would really appreciate some help on resolving this issue. Thank you all.

Thanks

Comment: Just leaving this in case anyone comes across this question like I did. This is a current bug with reactstrap https://github.com/reactstrap/reactstrap/issues/677

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer works for me:
https://github.com/reactstrap/reactstrap/issues/677#issuecomment-373482596

You need to fix the `height` to the class `.carousel-inner`.

Answer (score 1):

Still having problems?
Are you using Mozilla Firefox?

Try setting "backface-visibility" to "visible" on .carousel-inner .item.